# Sliding window of width n over the given iterable

Tags: python, function, python-itertools, windowed

I have a sequence, window size and step:

```
seq = [0,1,2,3,4]
n=4
step=2

from more_itertools import windowed
list(windowed([0,1,2,3,4], n, fillvalue=0, step=step))
```

result:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4, 0)]
```

but I need:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4, 0), (4, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Please help me find a solution

Comment: @JackMoody My interpretation is that the window should slide forward by `step=2` elements in each iteration - so the first window starts at `0`, the 2nd at `2`, and the 3rd at `4`. Then the input is exhausted and no further windows are returned.

Comment: the window moves in steps of 2, (4, 0, 0, 0) is just the next window shift. No, I can not add to the manual, because this is just an example, and the window pitch and its size can be different, as well as the sequence

Comment: I see. Thanks @Aran-Fey.

Comment: Once the fillvalue is used once (it is used in the second tuple), more_itertools stops. This is as should be expected.

Comment: a ugly way to solve this, append 0 in tail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [padded](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.padded)?

```
seq = [0,1,2,3,4]
n=4
step=2

from more_itertools import windowed, padded
list(windowed(padded(seq, 0, n=n, next_multiple=True), n, step=step))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write your own `windowed` function:

```
def windowed(iterable, size, fillvalue=None, step=1):
    for i in range(0, len(iterable), step):
        window = iterable[i:i+size]
        window += [fillvalue] * (size - len(window))
        yield window
```

```
>>> list(windowed([0,1,2,3,4], 4, fillvalue=0, step=2))
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

this should also work with iterables and not just sequences:

```
from itertools import islice

def sliding_window(seq, n, step, fillvalue=None):
    it = iter(seq)
    values = tuple(islice(it, n))
    while values:
        yield values + (n-len(values)) * (fillvalue, )
        values = values[step:] + tuple(islice(it, step))
```

the function outputs:

```
print(list(sliding_window(seq, n, step, fillvalue=0)))
# [(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4, 0), (4, 0, 0, 0)]
```

most of it is borrowed from the original itertools recipe for a [sliding window](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/itertools-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider [`more_itertools.stagger`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.stagger):

**Given**

```
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit


iterable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

**Code**

Get all results from sliding windows:

```
windows = list(mit.stagger(iterable, offsets=(0, 1, 2, 3), longest=True, fillvalue=0))
windows
# [(0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 5, 0), (3, 5, 0, 0), (5, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Next, filter out the desired results:

```
[w for i, w in enumerate(windows) if not (i % 2)]
# [(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 5, 0), (5, 0, 0, 0)]
```

or [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) the iterable:

```
list(it.islice(windows, 0, None, 2))
# [(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 5, 0), (5, 0, 0, 0)]
```